# Nginx not matching the location

Tags: nginx

Can anyone tell me why is this ngnix config doesn't match all URL that starts with /admin :

```
    location /admin {
        alias {{path_to_static_page}}/admin/build/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
```

It always fall back to the default content of location / . However, I hardcoded all the possible URL in the Nginx config, it works and only matches the hard coded URL, something like :

```
        location /admin {
            alias {{path_to_static_page}}/admin/build/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /admin/news/ {
            alias {{path_to_static_page}}/admin/build/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /admin/another-url/ {
            alias {{path_to_static_page}}/admin/build/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The two solutions are not the same. And part of the problem may be the `/index.html` which is a URI that does not begin with `/admin`. Perhaps you mean to use `/admin/index.html`?

Comment: The index.html file is located in {{path_to_static_page}}/admin/build/ , my goal is to whenever someone type /admin/something, they should see the index.html file inside the   {{path_to_static_page}}/admin/build/ directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final term of the `try_files` statement is a URI. The URI of the `index.html` file at `/path/to/admin/build/index.html` is `/admin/index.html`.

Using `alias` and `try_files` in the same `location` block [can be problematic](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97).

You may want to use a more reliable solution:

```
location ^~ /admin {
    alias /path/to/admin/build;
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /admin/index.html last; }
}
```

The `location` and `alias` values should both end with `/` or neither end with `/`. The `^~` operator will prevent other regular expression `location` blocks from matching any URI that begins with `/admin`. See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.